# What do you call someone with the same occupation as you, but works for a different company?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, terminology, phrase-requests, collective-nouns

What do you call someone who works in the same field or occupation as you do, but in a different company or organization?

Answer (score 13):

Using **fellow** in conjunction with the field or occupation is common, as in *Walker and his fellow governors*.

The first single word that springs to mind is **peers**, indicating people of equal standing, i.e. similar responsibilities and status. To indicate direct analogues/equivalents you could use **counterparts**, for example if you are benefits officer for Company X, the benefits officer at Company Y would be your counterpart. Your **complement** on the other hand is one in the opposite role; if you the head of sales at A Ltd., the head of purchasing is your complement at B Ltd. Your **cohorts** are those close to you in tenure or experience, especially in fields with long training programs such as medicine or architecture. If you are a third-year resident, all the other third-year residents in the country are your cohorts (and collectively, your cohort).

To emphasize a shared identity, you could use a variety of words suggesting membership in a club or family: members of the journalistic **fraternity**, your **compatriots** in the social sciences, our **confreres** at the German Embassy.

Answer (score 5):

**Confrere**

> a fellow member of a fraternity, profession, etc.;

Answer (score 3):

> **counterpart** - a person or thing having the same function or characteristics as another

Answer (score 0):

If you’re in a specific, identifiable position and want to refer to the equivalent individual in another organisation, you could call such a person your [**opposite number**](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/opposite+number) (or, informally, [**oppo**](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/oppo)).