# What is the word for someone who has (or had) the same job as someone else?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, business-language

I mean two people who have the same job, but do not work together at the same place. I'm thinking about the word "counterpart", but I'm not sure about it!
For example, considering two American film directors such as Spielberg and Altman, can I say that Altman (who is dead now) is Spielberg's late counterpart?

Comment: -1 How is this different from [the question you asked eight hours previous to this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/440764/what-is-the-word-for-someone-who-had-the-same-job-or-position-as-someone-else-in)?

Comment: The other question specifically refers to a temporal difference between the two people (so predecessor is appropriate), this question implies a spatial difference (so predecessor isn’t appropriate here). Very slightly different, and a different example would clarify this.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/56822/14666 "What do you call someone with the same occupation as you, but works for a different company?" ; https://english.stackexchange.com/q/11458/14666 "Word for 'someone who does the same job as me'"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do you call someone with the same occupation as you, but works for a different company?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56822/what-do-you-call-someone-with-the-same-occupation-as-you-but-works-for-a-differ)

Answer (score 1):

For someone who *has* the same job as someone else earlier, I would recommenced using the word **successor**.

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/successor) defines **successor** as:

> *noun*
>
> a person or thing that succeeds, or follows, another; esp., one who succeeds to an office, title, etc.

As for someone who *had* the same job as someone who currently does, I would recommend the term **predecessor**

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/predecessor) defines **predecessor** as:

> *noun*
>
> 1. a person who precedes or preceded another, as in office

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

> Robert Altman directed the *M*A*S*H* movie. 
>   The works of Steven Spielberg,
>   a ***fellow*** director, may be better known to today’s audiences.

Some terms, while not explicitly saying
that people are or were in the same job, field, or profession,
imply it by juxtaposition:

> Speaking of movies, we know from *Amadeus*
>   that Mozart and Salieri were ***contemporaries***;
>   they were in the same ***cohort***. 
>   While the movie depicted them as ***rivals***,
>   [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonio_Salieri#Interaction_with_Mozart) suggests that they might have been
>   “mutually respectful ***peers***”. 
>   Beethoven was also their ***contemporary***.

> Johann Sebastian Bach was ***senior*** to Salieri, Mozart and Beethoven
>   by about 60-70 years.
>
> In my opinion,
>   Bach was a ***superior*** composer compared to his ***juniors***.

> Saruman was Sauron’s ***right-hand man*** —
>   or at least he thought he was, and aspired to be. 
>   In fact, he was far ***subordinate*** to the Dark Lord.

> Luke Skywalker was *an **apprentice*** to Yoda
>   in the ways of the Force and the Jedi Knights.

---

> ***fellow***:
>    [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fellow):
>
>     2 a : an equal in rank, power, or character : peer
>     - discussions among a group of fellows from the nearby Los Alamos National Laboratory
>          —Roger Lewin
>     3 : a member of a group having common characteristics; specifically : a member of an incorporated literary or scientific society
>
> ***contemporary***:
>    [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contemporary):
>
>     happening, existing, living, or coming into being
>       during the same period of time
>
> ***cohort***:
>    [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cohort):
>
>     group of individuals having a statistical factor (such as age or class membership) in common in a demographic study
>
> ***peer***:
>    [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peer):
>
>     one that is of equal standing with another
>
> ***senior***:
>    [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/senior):
>
>     1.  a person older than another
>     2a. a person with higher standing or rank
>
> ***superior***:
>    [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/superior):
>
>     of higher rank, quality, or importance
>
> ***right-hand man***:
>    [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/right-hand_man):
>
>     An indispensable helper or chief assistant.
>
> ***subordinate***:
>    [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subordinate):
>
>   - placed in or occupying a lower class, rank, or position : inferior -
>       a *subordinate* officer
>
>     submissive to or controlled by authority
>
> ***apprentice***:
>    [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apprentice):
>
>     one who is learning by practical experience
>       under skilled workers a trade, art, or calling -
>       a carpenter’s
>     *apprentice*